# Rolling sum of the next N elements, including the current element

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-sum

Good Morning,

I have the following dataframe:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = pd.DataFrame({'a': a})
```

I would like to create a column that sums the **next "n" rows** of column "a", **including the present value** of a; I tried:

```
n = 2
b["r"] = pd.rolling_sum(b.a, n) + a 
print(b)
   a     r
0  1   NaN
1  2   5.0
2  3   8.0
3  4  11.0
4  5  14.0
5  6  17.0
```

It would be delightful to have:

```
   a     r
0  1   1 + 2 + 3 = 6
1  2   2 + 3 + 4 = 9
2  3   3 + 4 + 5 = 12
3  4   4 + 5 + 6 = 15
4  5   5 + 6 + 0 = 11
5  6   6 + 0 + 0 = 6
```

Comment: From pandas 1.1 you can easily do this with [`FixedForwardWindowIndexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer.html#pandas.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## pandas >= 1.1

Pandas now supports "forward-looking window operations", see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#other-enhancements).

From 1.1, you can use [`FixedForwardWindowIndexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer.html#pandas.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer)

```
idx = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer
b['a'].rolling(window=idx(window_size=3), min_periods=1).sum()

0     6.0
1     9.0
2    12.0
3    15.0
4    11.0
5     6.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Note that this is still (at the time of writing) very buggy for datetime rolling operations - use with caution.

---

**pandas <= 1.0.X**

Without builtin support, you can get your output by first reversing your data, using `rolling_sum` with `min_periods=1`, and reverse again.

```
b.a[::-1].rolling(3, min_periods=1).sum()[::-1]

0     6.0
1     9.0
2    12.0
3    15.0
4    11.0
5     6.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```